# How i can use translate.use() method?

Tags: translation, thingsboard

I'm trying to change widget language. especially the name of the months.

[image]

```
self.ctx.translate.use('ru_RU').subscribe(response => {
    console.log('response',response)
})
```

doesn't work :(